# Delay in closing Powerpoint while doing close via VBA Macro

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have two macros in in a Powerpoint file in Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016 version.
1. Does saveas work
2. Closes Powerpoint

I run these two macros one by one using PowerPoint /m command line option. It's working fine. However, few times 2 macro close call is intermittently taking more time. When I move mouse on PowerPoint window after "close" macro is called, it closes instantly.   I am pretty sure first macro saved the file and finished execution successfully.  The close call macro code is below. I don't want to save any work.  I don't have any other Powerpoint process running. Please advice how can I speed up this? I wonder what's holding Powerpoint. Thank you.

```
Sub closeit()


With Application.ActivePresentation

    .Saved = True

    .Close

End With

Application.Quit


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The delay in macro 2's execution is most likely caused by macro 1 finishing the save. It's not possible to run two macros at once, so 2 can't run until 1 is done.

What's the logic behind two separate macros? It seems unneccessarily complicated, you could just add this code to the end of #1.

Comment: I am not calling both in parallel.  If I put that  macro 2  code lines end of macro 1(right after saveas), its not waiting for ActivePresentation.saveas to finish. That's why I had split them into two macros. I have put in file written successfully checks in my script before I call the second one to close. I am pretty sure that saveas is complete before I call second macro.  For some reason, Powerpoint just freezes before closing window intermittently. If I move mouse on it, it closes instantly.

Comment: Powerpoint responds to close call when that happens in 2-3 mins

Comment: Pausing execution to wait for other events is a common requirement. Here's an article about 3 ways to do that. Please note, while this article was written about Excel, they all work for Word for Windows as well: https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop

Comment: One caveat: the code in the myonlinetraininghub example is incorrect. #If VBA7 tells you whether the host is Office 2010 or later, but indicates nothing about the bitness. You want to use #If Win64 (which, confusingly, is about OFFICE bitness, not Windows). Or both if you need to first determine bitness and then whether it's Office 2010 or later.